# how to sum a total depending on a specific word in the next column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to Sum a total depending on another column contain certain words. 
Say A1-A2 Has Ben B1-B2 has 1,3. A3-A5 has Bob B3-B5 has 2,5,6. A6-A8 has Bill B6-B8 has 3,9,1. How would I then add up these totals, for all cells containing either ben or bob or Bill. To put in column C1 Ben 4, C2 Bob 13,C3 Bill 13.

Say if i had more names to add how would this work with adding more names to the same sheet.

This is what Ive got so far, I've put in the second small macro because i need to use this to determine the last cell with Ben for example, instead of using 1Row which is the last cell in the column.

```
Sub SumValues()

Dim I As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim first As Variant
Dim last As Variant
Dim Sum1 As Variant
Dim Sum2 As Variant

Range("A1").Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For I = 1 To 1

   Cells.Find(What:="ben", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    first = ActiveCell.Row
   Next I
    For lCol = first To (lRow - 1)

   Cells.Find(What:="ben", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

   Next lCol
last = ActiveCell.Row
Range("G1").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(first, 2), Cells(last, 2)))

    End Sub

Sub SelectBetween()
Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long
On Error GoTo errhandler
findrow = Range("A:A").Find("bob", Range("A1")).Row
findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("ben", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
Range("B" & findrow & ":B" & findrow2 - 1).Select
errhandler:
MsgBox "No Cells containing specified text found"
End Sub
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated!!

Comment: If you are working with macros, you are not working with VB.NET - more likely vba.  Consult the helpful usage guidance on  the tags

Comment: And if you **are** working with VBA, please remove the inappropriate [macros] tag (which says "***DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages. Use the respective [vba] tags instead.***")

Comment: And if this is Excel, why don't you just use a `SUMIF` formula?

Comment: Thanks, your right I could use a sumif, there is more like 100 values i need to find the sum of.  I then was thinking of using, 1 sheet with all these values in, then using a find function, to look for the first value, then store the address as a variable, then loop the find function but i then cant get the last value, as it loops round to the beginning before it exits the loop.  Then if i could get the last value i need. Then sum address 1 to address 2 and repeat, for each value in my list.    Hope this makes sense.